# Program works when run with scala, get compile errors when try to compile it with scalac

Tags: scala, compilation

I am testing the code below, does a basic database query.  It works fine when I run it from the CLI using "scala dbtest.scala", but gives me compile errors when I try to compile it with scalac :

```
[sean@ibmp2 pybackup]$ scalac dbtest.scala
dbtest.scala:5: error: expected class or object definition
val conn_str = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/svn?user=svn&password=svn"
^
dbtest.scala:8: error: expected class or object definition
classOf[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
^
dbtest.scala:11: error: expected class or object definition
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conn_str)
^
dbtest.scala:12: error: expected class or object definition
try {
^
four errors found
```

```
import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager, ResultSet};
import java.util.Date

// Change to Your Database Config
val conn_str = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/svn?user=xx&password=xx"

// Load the driver
classOf[com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]

// Setup the connection
val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conn_str)
try {
    // Configure to be Read Only
    val statement = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)

    // Execute Query
    val rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM backup")

    // Iterate Over ResultSet
    var svnFiles = Set[String]()
    while (rs.next) {
        val repos = rs.getString("repos")
        val lm = rs.getDate("lastModified")
        val lb = rs.getDate("lastBackedup")
        if (lm.getTime() > lb.getTime()) {
          println(repos + " needs backing up")
          svnFiles += repos
        }
        else {
          println(repos + " doesn't need backing up")
        }
    }
    println(svnFiles)
}
finally {
    conn.close
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need either a class, object, or trait at the top level to make it a legal source to compile. `scala` interpreter expects definitions and expressions, whereas `scalac` expects something that can turn into Java `.class` files.

Comment: OK, but it's legal to run the code as I have it like a script through command line scala?  It does work from the CLI

Comment: Yes, as a script, Scala does not require a top level container.

Comment: Also, reminder from ```scala -help```: ```All options to scalac (see scalac -help) are also allowed.``` So, go ahead and run it with something like ```scala -optimise dbtest.scala```

Answer (score 2):

```
//imports here

object DbTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  // your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called HelloWorld.scala, and enter the following:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
```

To compile the example, we use scalac, the Scala compiler. scalac works like most compilers: it takes a source file as argument, maybe some options, and produces one or several object files. The object files it produces are standard Java class files.

From the command line, run:

```
scalac HelloWorld.scala
```

This will generate a few class files in the current directory. One of them will be called HelloWorld.class, and contains a class which can be directly executed using the scala command.

Once compiled, a Scala program can be run using the scala command. Its usage is very similar to the java command used to run Java programs, and accepts the same options. The above example can be executed using the following command, which produces the expected output:

Now run:

```
scala HelloWorld.scala
```

Now "Hello World", will be printed to the console.

After researching this functionality, I found an article, which explains this in detail, and posted that information here on SO to help programmers understand this aspect of Scala development.

Source: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html